# How can I compile and run this 1989 written C program?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, vm-implementation

I found this amazing piece of work by Arthur Whitney - http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Incunabulum

It compiled with a few warnings

```
$ gcc-4.7 incuna.c -o incuna.o
incuna.c: In function 'ma':
incuna.c:8:15: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]
incuna.c: In function 'pi':
incuna.c:26:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]
incuna.c: In function 'nl':
incuna.c:26:24: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]
incuna.c: In function 'pr':
incuna.c:28:10: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]
incuna.c: In function 'ex':
incuna.c:35:36: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
incuna.c:35:25: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
incuna.c: In function 'noun':
incuna.c:37:57: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
incuna.c: In function 'wd':
incuna.c:39:21: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strlen' [enabled by default]
```

But it segfaulted on entering a basic input `1 + 1`.

```
./incuna.o
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
1 + 1
[1]    11525 segmentation fault  ./incuna.o
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the difference in C compiler since 1989.

How would I be able to run this? Can I get this working on recent Linux/Mac? or on a VirtualBox VM? or anything else?

My Google searches turned up nothing related.

Comment: Perhaps you could try running the program in gdb to see more info?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` perhaps? Edit: corrected syntax

Comment: This looks like buffer overflow due to gets()

Comment: `1+1` doesn't segfault. Just thought you should know.

Comment: @leppie, added it, same result.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar, strange. `1+1` does segfault for me.

Comment: @user1527166 - Look at my updated answer, your spacing is wrong. In your question you said "1 + 1" that will seg fault, you have to enter "1+1" (no spaces)

Comment: Found this page with some explanation of the code: http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/AIOJ/AIOJ.htm

Comment: More explanation: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sayeret-lambda/Oxffk3aeUP4/QEuZocgVh5UJ

Comment: More explanation: http://archive.vector.org.uk/trad/v094/hui094_85.pdf‎ [pdf scanned from journal]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It converts pointers to `int` and `long` and vice-versa. This breaks with 64-bit architectures in which they have different sizes.

Compile it for a 32-bit target. E.g., with “-arch i386” using clang/LLVM on Mac OS X.

Comment: Or `-m32` for gcc. This could be a great example of a program that's not 64-bit safe. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would wager a guess that it segfaulted because of this:

> incuna.c:8:15: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]

If malloc is not declared, then it's not going to allocate you memory and you'll end up dereferencing a null and that could lead to a seg fault.

After including:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

The warnings for `printf()`, `malloc()`, and `strlen()` are gone. The code runs and works if you input:

```
1+1
```

Note the ***spacing is important*** here:

```
1 + 1
```

will segfault.

Comment: You likely forgot to include <stdlib.h>.

Comment: @SSHThis, including stdlib removed the warning, but the segfault remains.

Comment: Wonderful! This and the answer below by Eric to use `i386` arch worked on my 64 bit environment :)

Comment: Add `#include <string.h>` to provide a declaration for `strlen()` too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Good point, I didn't turn on -Wall so I missed that one in there. Updated

Comment: not declaring `malloc()` won't cause it to return zero and somehow fail to allocate memory!  If the program still links properly then malloc() is still there, and being called, though as is pointed out in the proper answer, the return value may be treated incorrectly if a pointer and an int are of different sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Run it through the preprocessor only:

gcc -E interp.c > interp-pp.c

Then prettify it in an editor, then use a debugger to watch what it does.

Answer (score 3):

On my system (AMD64 Win 8), it appears that pointer values often have the top bit set, so treating a pointer as an integer (which this program does) will misbehave and crash.

Changing the `qv(a)` function ("query verb") allows the program to run:

```
qv(a){R a<'a';}
```

should be

```
qv(a){R a<'a'&&a>0;}
```

or

```
qv(a)unsigned a;{R a<'a';}
```

Here's a link to a [minimally-modified version](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/commit/3e81b6e4d9b6cb73eefd1dc3b04036a4de7f8cd6) that should compile without warnings (with gcc, default options) and execute (with correct input).

Comment: I've created a github project, extending this bizarre little program. [link](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca)